# Find all symlinks to a directory and change target to another directory

Tags: find, symlink

I have a bunch of symlinks in `/home` to files and sub-directories in `/foo`. I want to target the new directory, `/bar`.

My approach was to look at all invalid symlinks and verify that they were pointing to `/foo`. I then did the following:

```
sudo find . -type l -! -exec test -e {} \; -exec sh -c '\
   old_link_target=$(readlink "$0"); \
   new_link_target=${old_link_target//foo/bar}; \
   ln -snf $new_link_target $0' {} \;
```

However, I want a more precise approach that would not include the initial step of putting eyes on the invalid symlinks. So, for the sake of this question, assume `/foo` still exists so another approach is required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GNUly:

```
find . -lname '/foo*' -printf '%p\0%l\0' |
  awk -vRS='\0' '
    {
      getline target
      sub("^/foo", "/bar", target)
      printf("%s\0%s\0", target, $0)
    }' |
  xargs -r0n2 ln -sfT
```

Or with recent GNU `sed`:

```
find . -lname '/foo*' -printf '%l\0%p\0' |
  sed -z 's|^/foo|/bar|;n' |
  xargs -r0n2 ln -sfT
```

Beware that you will potentially be affecting the ownership of the symlinks (so for instance, their original author won't be able to remove them any longer if they're in a directory they don't own but have write access to and has the `t` bit set (like `/tmp`)).

To prevent that, you could use GNU `tar` instead:

```
find . -lname '/foo*' -print0 |
  tar --null -T - -cf - --transform='s@^/foo@/bar@' |
  tar xpf -
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tiny test set:

```
mkdir ./tmp1 ./tmp2    
touch ./tmp1/file1 ./tmp2/file2
ln -s ./tmp1 ./tmp3
ls -H ./tmp3
```

#### OUTPUT

```
file1
```

So now I'll...

```
mount --bind ./tmp2 ./tmp1
ls -H ./tmp3
```

#### OUTPUT

```
file2
```

tada! Now all links that once pointed to `./tmp1` will automatically point to `./tmp2` - as, in fact, so does `./tmp1` because they are the same mountpoint. Had `./tmp2` contained child-mounts I might have done:

```
mount --rbind ./tmp2 ./tmp1
```

And recursively `--bind` `mount`ed the trees. And that doesn't even the scratch the surface on the Linux kernel's vfs [*shared subtrees*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) `mount` options.

On a Linux system you don't have to concern yourself overmuch with what directory a file points to because you can atomically affect that file's location using the kernel's virtual filesystem mount tree - it is at your disposal. And you can manage the entire thing in `/etc/fstab`.

```
>>/etc/fstab \
printf '%s %s none bind,defaults 0 0\n' \
    "/bar" "/foo"
```

And your problems are solved.

Comment: +1 This may or may not apply to a particular situation (if distributing files across many computers, it's much easier to fix it once rather than on every machine; you may not have permission to mount; the current target may still need to exist and be accessible), but it's a good strategy to consider if you find yourself trying to change symlink targets to fix a problem.